# Prevent scrapy reponse from being added to cache

Tags: scrapy

I am crawling a website that returns pages with a captcha and a status code 200 suggesting everything is ok. This causes the page to be put into scrapy's cache.

I want to recrawl these pages later. But if they are in the cache, they won't get recrawled.

Is it feasible to overload the process_response function from the httpcache middleware or to look for a specific string in the reponse html and override the 200 code with an error code?

What would be the easiest way to keep scrapy from putting certain responses into the cache.

Comment: When you crawl them again can't you use `dont_filter= True` on the requests?

Comment: I am doing that already. Maybe it has to do with the proxy middleware that I am using. Right now, I am trying to define a custom httpcache policy to solve it...

Comment: Tell me how your worked it out. I find this question interesting maybe useful for the future

Answer (score 3):

Scrapy uses [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache.HttpCacheMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache.HttpCacheMiddleware) to cache http responses. To ignore this caching you can just set request meta keyword `dont_cache` to True like:

```
yield Request(url, meta={'dont_cache': True})
```

The docs above also mention how to disable it project-wide with a setting if you are interested in that too.